# Meteor doesn't call "rerended" on data change

Tags: meteor

I have the autorun function in rendered callback:

```
Template.drawFlow.rendered = ->
    outerData = this
    this.autorun ->
        # do some work here using reactive collections
        s = Session.get("redrawLines")
        connectRecursive outerData.data.tasks, outerData.data.startTask
```

What I want is that on data change in this.autorun to reexecute the function. Right now it doesn't do it, so I am wondering why.

**Update**
updated the code above, and also, on some events I do:

```
Session.set('redrawLines', moment())
```

which should invalidate the computation inside the autorun function.
Also, the "outerData" variable should be reactive, as it's from "data" section of the IronRouter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.autorun is a reactive computation, but you need a reactive *source* within that autorun function in order for the view to be rendered upon update of that data.

Reactive sources in Meteor include Session variables, cursors, Meteor.user, and more. Here's a good read that should help you out:

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually the code contains reactive data (will now update the code in question). Does it mean that reactive variable is getting used?

Comment: What version of meteor are you using? Just noticed this but the rendered function is actually onRendered in the current version of meteor - that could be your issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I've made it onRendered, then I've made a reference to that reactive var (don't know if it was needed), and looks like it works now! Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Final working code, which fires after DOM is finshed (as opposed to my solution):

```
Template.drawFlow.onRendered ->
    console.log "Template.drawFlow.onRendered"
    this.autorun ->
        data = Router.current().data()
        Tracker.afterFlush ->
            console.log "dom is now created"
```